# svg elements doesn't show under certain resolution in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, svg, graphics

In ff version 46.0.1 with view-port (it's important, because this problem shows only under specific view-ports) 1920 × 922 some svg elements doesn't show after interaction.

```
function createCircle(x, y, space) {
    circle = document.createElementNS(svg, "circle");
    circle.setAttributeNS("","cx", x);
    circle.setAttributeNS("","cy", y);
    circle.setAttributeNS("","r", 20);
    circle.setAttributeNS("","stroke", "black");
    circle.setAttributeNS("","stroke-width", 3);
    circle.setAttributeNS("","fill", "gray");
    circle.setAttributeNS("","onclick", "createNode(evt, 'left', " + space + ")");
    graph.appendChild(circle);
}

function createNode(evt, direction, space) {
    var target = evt.target;
    var y = parseInt(target.getAttribute("cy"));
    var x = parseInt(target.getAttribute("cx"));
    if(direction == "left") {
        target.setAttribute("onclick", "createNode(evt, 'right', " + space + ")");
        var cx = x - space;
        var cy = y - 80;
        createLine(x - 5, y - 20, cx, cy);
    } else {
        target.removeAttribute("onclick");
        var cx = x + space;
        var cy = y - 80;
        createLine(x + 5, y - 20, cx, cy);
    }

    if(cy > 0) {
        createCircle(cx, cy, space/2);
    } else {
        target.removeAttribute("onclick");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var graph = document.getElementById("graph");
    createCircle(180, 470, 90);

});
```

...but elemnts will show when I resize a window.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

I found resolution. Some parent DOM element have
    display: table-cell;
when i remove it, my app starts working fine.

Comment: you can report Firefox SVG bugs [via this link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG)

Comment: ok, thanks for advice